# The meaning of the word "good" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

> If an article does what is claimed for it, it will be a valuable good.

This sentence is taken from the advertisements. I'd like to know what the meaning of "good" is. Is "good" correctly used in the sentence? Thanks a trillion.

Comment: Technically speaking, your cited example is "grammatical", but it's extremely clunky phrasing. And almost all articulate writers today would use ***commodity*** rather than ***good*** here.

Answer (score 3):

**[Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_(economics))** here refers to an object in the economic sense as in "goods and services"

> possessions, especially movable effects or personal property.

[[Source]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/goods)

Comment: Is it correct without "s" in the word "good"? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The "s" just makes the word plural in this case.